# Aura Documentation Site is Down

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I can't access the aura doc [site](http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs).  From my perspective, it's been down over a week.  This is a sanity check:  Is it me or is it the site?  Is there an alternative?

Comment: what site? can you share the link please? http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs ?

Comment: Yep... it is down. Not just you :-)

Comment: As an alternative to access the aura documentation you could use the base domain/aura docs like in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs**  gives me a network error.

> Network Error (tcp_error)
>
> A communication error occurred: "" The Web Server may be down, too
>   busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to
>   requests. You may wish to try again at a later time...

I tried checking auradocs with my base domain in sandbox and it looks fine.

**Alternative solution:** You can try using the auradocs with your based domain like below.

https://yourdomainhere.lightning.force.com/auradocs

Comment: i think the op is refereing to http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs ;)

Comment: @codeyinthecloud thanks.  I tried it your way and it works.  Is there a difference in content between using an instance domain and going to the independent site?

Comment: @GabrielRivera The key difference AFAIK is that the base domain docs has all the references to your internal lightning metadata like components from different namespaces with in your org